# exact lines from text file with multiple sublines in linux

Tags: sql, linux

i am using UTL_FILE utility in oracle to get the data  in to csv file.

sample of output in the test.csv file is

```
"sno","name"
"1","hari is in singapore
ramesh is in USA"
"2","pong is in chaina
chang is in malaysia
vilet is in uk"
```

now i am counting the number of records in the testr.csv  by using linux commans as

```
awk 'END{print NR-1}' test.csv
```

here i am getting the record count as

```
5      (ACCORDING TO LINUX)
```

but if i calculate the number of records by using `select * from test`;

```
 COUNT(*)
----------                 (ACCORDING TO DATA BASE)
        2
```

can any body help me how to count the exact lines in the test.csv file

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't just count the lines that start with a number?

```
egrep -c "^\"[0-9]" test.csv
```

output:

```
2
```

Comment: if i get the like  this  "","", then egrep -c "^\"[0-9]" is showing zero lines how to handle this case